# confused in how to use old+new in plsql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where in i have to sum up employee hours based on same date,same reason code  and same employee id.I have an entire trigger which is of about 250 lines i am not writing an entire trigger i have just written the merge clause where the change is to be done

```
MERGE INTO stg_ta_payroll
     USING (SELECT :NEW.ID_TM_ENR ID_TM_ENR,
                   TO_NUMBER (:NEW.ID_STR_RT) ID_STR_RT,
                   :NEW.ID_EM ID_EM,
                   NVL (TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (:NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN, 'YYMMDD')), 0)
                      V_TA_DATE,
                   V_SESSION_NO V_SESSION_NO,
                   :NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN TS_EM_TM_IN,
                   :NEW.TS_EM_TM_OUT TS_EM_TM_OUT,
                   DECODE (
                      :NEW.TY_TM,
                      '0', NVL (TO_CHAR (:NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN, 'HH24MI'), '0000'),
                      ' ')
                      V_TIME_IN,
                   DECODE (
                      :NEW.TY_TM,
                      '0', NVL (TO_CHAR (:NEW.TS_EM_TM_OUT, 'HH24MI'),
                                '0000'),
                      ' ')
                      V_TIME_OUT,
                   V_MGR_OVRD V_MGR_OVRD,
                   :NEW.ID_MGR ID_MGR,
                   DECODE (:NEW.TY_TM, 'XX', '9', :NEW.TY_TM) TY_TM,
                   :NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR OTHER_HRS_STR,
                   V_AREA V_AREA,
                   V_ASSC_NAME V_ASSC_NAME,
                   V_MISC_WAGES_DESC V_MISC_WAGES_DESC,
                   V_SHRT_STR_NAME V_SHRT_STR_NAME,
                   (:NEW.HRS_STR + :NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR) TOT_HRS
              FROM DUAL) STG
        ON (    TIME_ENT_ID = STG.ID_TM_ENR
            AND TO_NUMBER (STR_ID) = TO_NUMBER (STG.ID_STR_RT)
            AND EMP_ID = STG.ID_EM
            AND TA_DATE = STG.V_TA_DATE
            AND MISC_WAGES_CODE = STG.TY_TM)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET
      STATUS = NULL,
      TIME_IN = STG.V_TIME_IN,
      TIME_OUT = STG.V_TIME_OUT,
      MGR_OVERRIDE = STG.V_MGR_OVRD,
      MGR_EMP_NO = STG.ID_MGR,
      MISC_WAGES_HRS =
         (  (NVL ( (:OLD.OTHER_HRS_STR), 0))
          + (NVL ( (:NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR), 0))),
      AREA = STG.V_AREA,
      ASSOCIATE_NAME = STG.V_ASSC_NAME,
      MISC_WAGES_DESC = STG.V_MISC_WAGES_DESC,
      SHRT_STR_NAME = STG.V_SHRT_STR_NAME,
      HRS = STG.TOT_HRS,
      STG_OSB_PROCESS_DATE = NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (TIME_ENT_ID,
               STATUS,
               STR_ID,
               EMP_ID,
               TA_DATE,
               SESSION_NO,
               TIME_IN,
               TIME_OUT,
               MGR_OVERRIDE,
               MGR_EMP_NO,
               MISC_WAGES_CODE,
               MISC_WAGES_HRS,
               AREA,
               ASSOCIATE_NAME,
               MISC_WAGES_DESC,
               SHRT_STR_NAME,
               HRS,
               STG_LOAD_DATE,
               STG_EVENT_ID,
               STG_OSB_STATUS)
       VALUES (STG.ID_TM_ENR,
               NULL,
               STG.ID_STR_RT,
               STG.ID_EM,
               STG.V_TA_DATE,
               STG.V_SESSION_NO,
               STG.V_TIME_IN,
               STG.V_TIME_OUT,
               STG.V_MGR_OVRD,
               STG.ID_MGR,
               STG.TY_TM,
               STG.OTHER_HRS_STR,
               STG.V_AREA,
               STG.V_ASSC_NAME,
               STG.V_MISC_WAGES_DESC,
               STG.V_SHRT_STR_NAME,
               STG.TOT_HRS,
               SYSDATE,
               seq_stg_event_id.NEXTVAL,
               0);

COMMIT;
```

I have to sum up only the other_hrs_str column based on  same date(TA_DATE),same reason code(TY_TM)  and same employee id(ID_EM).How can i go about Adding based on old+new value of other_hrs_str on these 3 conditions
Can any one help please.

Comment: Can you try to format the query so there is a chance of understanding it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to SUM() something, this requires GROUP BY 
Here is a limitation: columns in your output could be either columns from GROUP BY, or some aggregate functions (SUM, COUNT, etc)

You can avoid by splitting query in 2 parts:

1. key column + sum()
2. key column + other columns

Then you just join this 2 queried based on key.

:OLD and :NEW contains 2 versions of same **row** before and after a statement that fired a trigger. This means that if you need to sum something that is not available in just **one record**, you would need to write a SELECT statement to get that information.

But, mind the [Mutating-Table Restriction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#g1699708)

So, my suggesting is if your SUM() is from the same table that trigger is fired for, make SUM calculation in INSERT/UPDATE statement (than it would be available in :NEW record).

What is your current problem?